# How to spin bitmap along with Circle ProgressBar?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-custom-view, android-bitmap, ondraw

I am trying to modify a little this library: https://github.com/Shinelw/ColorArcProgressBar

And this is what i've done so far, **without the purple circle indicator**:
[arc progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3KA5.jpg)

My question is: how can i animate the purple circle along with the progress(as shown in the image)?

Inside ColorArcProgressBar class  that extends View, at onDraw method, this is how the progress is draw: `canvas.drawArc(bgRect, startAngle, currentAngle, false, progressPaint);`

and the animation is

```
private void setAnimation(float last, float current, int length) {
    progressAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(last, current);
    progressAnimator.setDuration(length);
    progressAnimator.setTarget(currentAngle);
    progressAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            currentAngle = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            curValues = currentAngle / k;
        }
    });
    progressAnimator.start();

}
```

I managed to position the purple bitmat at the start of the progress like this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(mIcon,bgRect.left+mIcon.getWidth()/2 +30, bgRect.bottom - 40 +mIcon.getHeight()/2 , null);
```

Now, how can I animate it along the arc like the progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't try this out, if it's not right it's close...

```
    // since currentAngle is a "sweep" angle, the 
    // final angle should be current + start
    float thetaD = startAngle + currentAngle;
    if (thetaD > 360F) {
        thetaD -= 360F;
    }

    // convert degrees to radians
    float theta = (float) Math.toRadians(thetaD);

    // polar to Cartesian coordinates
    float x = (float) (Math.cos(theta) * bgRect.width() / 2) + bgRect.centerX();
    float y = (float) (Math.sin(theta) * bgRect.height() / 2) + bgRect.centerY();

    canvas.drawBitmap(mIcon, x - mIcon.getWidth()/2, y - mIcon.getHeight()/2 , null);
```

It helped that your bitmap is circular, so we didn't have to rotate that...

Comment: I tried some things, but now i see that i forgot we need to work vith cos and sin, my x and y was the same but without cos and sin.